# How can i export my jar with libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a Java Project and i use a lot of library.

I choose the "Runnable Jar File" option when i want to export it. İf i choose the 3rd option at the picture, consist of a folder, it name is "JarName_Lib" and it has libraries. And it is working. But i want to unification jar file and libraries. İf i choose the one of the other two options, it doesn't working. How can i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a launch configuration first.

Run your program to create one.

Comment: I don't understand. Which class have main method, i choose it at the configuration.